# Formal name for operands of a join or join-like operation?

Tags: terminology, relation-algebra

In relational algebra, we have [join and join-like operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators).

I'm wondering if there is a formal name for the two operands on a join-like operation? For instance if we have two numbers, and wish to add them together, then the operation is *addition*, and its two operands are the *augend* and the *addend*.

Is there anything similar when the operation is *join*? What are the formal names for the two sets which act as operands/inputs to the join?